# Is Redis deployment on separate node really performant?

Tags: redis, memcached, in-memory-database

Based on below latentcy comparisons given at https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832 SSD Read is almost similar to Network Read in same datacenter in terms of cost.

I am trying to understand if Redis deployment on separate node/cluster will be performant due to network latency introduced? Won't deploying Redis on app nodes itself be a better option? This is assuming app nodes are using SSD disks and data is sharded across app nodes.

This is for a large deployment with more than 10 app nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously if you can run Redis on the same node as your app you'll get better latency than over the network (and you can also use Unix socket to reduce it more).

But the questions you need to ask your self:

1. How are you going to shard the data between the app nodes?
2. What about high availability?
3. Are there cases where one app node will need data from another node?
4. Can you be sure the load will be evenly distributed between the nodes so no Redis node will get out of memory?
5. What about scale out? How are you going to reshard the data?